# Getting Access Denied when using Odoo External APIs on an inactive user

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

Im getting an access denied error when trying to do any operation on an inactive user in Odoo 14. When making the user active the API requests are working normally.

This is not the case when on my Odoo 13 instance. Is this a change that was made starting Odoo 14 or am I missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: The login method will call the search method to get users using their login. The search method will call [_where_calc](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/a3daaf4d3a22e403ca891a1d396380e118020164/odoo/models.py#L4197) and, if the object (`res.user` record) has a field named ``active``, filter out all inactive. The login will fail at line [618](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/addons/base/models/res_users.py#L618). It seems that the login method was overridden to search also inactive users

Comment: @Kenly so it is no longer possible ? or is there a possible way to override it just like it was happening in Odoo 13 ?

Comment: By looking at the code reference from Kenly and what he mentioned, if you can override _login method then it will be possible.

Comment: @AhmadSabeh Archived users should not be able to log in. But if you want to let archived users to log in any way, just override [_get_login_domain](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/addons/base/models/res_users.py#L601) and add `('active', '=', False)` to the returned domain.

Comment: @Kenly how can i do this via the external API methods for python?

Comment: You can't pass the domain to the login method, so you can't do it using only the external API